# Android FCM icon issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM for sending push notifications to multiple devices but the system generated notification is white square in color when app is in background.

Comment: you should post some code what are you using for showing notification

Comment: add screenshot and code please

Comment: May be you app icon color is white, Explain further your issue.

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_push_notification" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
@asad.qazi

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support Lollipop Material Icons then make transparent icons for Lollipop and above version. Please refer following https://design.google.com/icons/

Implementation of Notification Builder for below and above Lollipop OS version would be:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent);
} else { 
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @seema but I'm using payload of type 'Notification' so that system generates the notification when application is in background. I think designing new material icon for notification will solve the problem.